# Apache 2.4 on RHEL 7 - replacing mod_perl.so and VirtualHost variables for CGI::Compile

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl-module, apache2.4, mod-perl, rhel7

I'm currently porting and old Perl-based application into AWS. I successfully made Perl run alongside Apache 2.4 and even got my PostgreSQL database up and running.

Then I proceeded configure Apache's `httpd.conf` to properly load all the resources necessary for the system to work. I got most of them up and running after some research. However, I simply can't get around `LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so`

From what I've researched so far, `mod_perl.so` has been deprecated in Apache 2.4 on RHEL 7, and as indicated on [RHEL 7's website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-package_replacements) this module should be replaced by something else - they suggest `mod_fcgid`, but after discussing the issue internally, we decided to go with `PSGI's CGI::Emulate::PSGI` and `CGI::Compile` as our replacement, basically because it would allow us to not mess up hundreds of old scripts to change print orders.

However, I can´t get them to work. Trying to call them withing a script causes Perl to not find `CGI::Compile`, and attempting to install this module through CPAN results in an error `MIYAGAWA/CGI-Compile-0.22.tar.gz             : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Build.PL ' returned status 512`

Below is an example of the code I´m using (file myPSGIScript.psgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use CGI::Compile;
use CGI::Emulate::PSGI;

my $sub = CGI::Compile->compile("/var/www/cgi-bin/testScript.pl");
my $app = CGI::Emulate::PSGI->handler($sub);
```

Where testScript.pl is a simulation of one of our scripts, including calls to CGI and other modules that we need, placed on the same folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI qw/:standard :html/;
$CGI::HEADERS_ONCE++;
$|=1;

print header;

use Pg;

my $test = param('test');

print <<BlocoWeb;
<html>
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
                <title>AWS Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <center>
                        <h1>
                                I'm working - $test -
                        </h1>
                        <br>
                        <form action='./testScript.pl'>
                                <input type='text' name='test' value='$test'>
                                <input type='submit'>
                        </form>
                </center>
        </body>
</html>
BlocoWeb
```

Am I misunderstanding how these libraries are supposed to work? Do I need to import them on Apache's `httpd.conf` or something? Or is it something else? Should I give up on this idea and use `mod_fcgid` instead - and how?

Also, `mod_perl` is what enables us to set certain parameters inside `<VirtualHost>` tag that are crucial for our application to work, namely `PerlOptions +GlobalRequest`, `PerlModule` and `PerlSetVar`. Is there a way using this method that would allow these to be set?

For reference, I'm on RHEL 7, Apache 2.4.6, Perl 5.16.3 inside Amazon's AWS.

---

EDIT: This is not the answer I was looking for, but it actually solved my issues, so I believe it's worth adding to this post just in case.

After a lot of research, I figured out from [Amazon's knowledge base](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/) that you can actually get your hands on `mod_perl.so` on RHEL 6 and 7 and other distributions they proide. All you have to do is enable their Extra Packages through the proper command. In my case:

```
sudo yum install –y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

After running the appropriate command, run `sudo yum repolist` and check if the following repositories are available:

```
 epel/x86_64                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64
 rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional/7Server/x86_64       Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional (RPMs)
```

If they are, you're ready to go and run `sudo yum install -y mod_perl` and it should be available for loading on Apache's conf file.

Again, this solved my issues for the moment but Red Hat's message is clear: don't use this unless you absolutely need to. If you can, upgrading your code to another newer module is the best thing to do.